# Как сохранять списки в файл и доставать их из файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сериализация, десериализация

Подскажите пожалуйста как сохранить в файл список такого вида:
`[('config.h', '.\mb_config.h', '83A7A716'), ('mainCpp.cpp', '.\mainCpp.cpp', '30FCD925')]`
А при следующем запуске программы, восстановить этот список для дальнейшего взаимодействия с ним...
Или я вообще не в правильном направлении двигаюсь и так параметры не принято хранить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для бинарной (без преобразования данных в текст) сериализации сложных объектов можно использовать модуль [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle):

```
In [55]: import pickle

In [56]: items = [('config.h', '.\mb_config.h', '83A7A716'), ('mainCpp.cpp', '.\mainCpp.cpp', '30FCD925')]

In [57]: with open(r'c:/temp/conf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    ...:     pickle.dump(items, f)
    ...:

In [58]: with open(r'c:/temp/conf.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    ...:     new = pickle.load(f)
    ...:

In [59]: new
Out[59]:
[('config.h', '.\\mb_config.h', '83A7A716'),
 ('mainCpp.cpp', '.\\mainCpp.cpp', '30FCD925')]
```

Для простых типов данных - числа, строки, булевые можно воспользоваться [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) / [YAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation):

```
In [60]: import json

In [61]: with open(r'c:/temp/conf.json', 'w') as f:
    ...:     json.dump(items, f)
    ...:

In [63]: with open(r'c:/temp/conf.json', 'rb') as f:
    ...:     new2 = json.load(f)
    ...:

In [64]: new2
Out[64]:
[['config.h', '.\\mb_config.h', '83A7A716'],
 ['mainCpp.cpp', '.\\mainCpp.cpp', '30FCD925']]
```

PS у данного подхода есть одно преимущество - JSON файлы являются "human readable", т.е. обычным текстовым файлом, который можно посмотреть и отредактировать любым текстовым редактором

Comment: Выбрал модуль pickle для использования:)